# Rspec tests failing intermittently and seemingly randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This is quite hard to explain and I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

If I run all my tests in one go, the same two fail every time.. However, if I run each block individually using `focus: true` they pass.. And, if I add tests in manually using the same method, they'll pass until I reach five tests.

There's no rhyme nor reason for this, or in fact any logic. I have specifically added a blank test in to see if there's some threading / variable issue but they still fail. It doesn't make sense.

What's worse is that 1/20 tests will actually pass.

- Using Rails4, Zeus (I've tried without) and Guard (also tried without)
- Using database cleaner, I'm truncating the tables after each block
- I've confirmed the model is recreated each run too

I have the following (simplified code). Although it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
before(:each) do
  @location = FactoryGirl.create(:location_full)
  @location.generate_defaults ## usually in a callback
  @mac = 'Some var'
end

it "checks the location's access is updated to var 1", focus: true do
  @location.update(bar: true)
  var = @location.generate_something(mac: @mac)
  var[:xyz].should eq 123
end    

...

it "checks the location's access is updated to var 2", focus: true do
  @location.update(bar: false)
  var2 = @location.generate_something(mac: @mac)
  var2[:xyz].should eq 456
end    

...

it "is a dummy test", focus: true do
  # nothing
end
```

Tests fail!

I thought it was something being retained in memory so I have even tried destroying all records before each. I have tried a sleep, reloading the record, changing databases.

Previously I was stuck in a controller test with ActionController::Live but that's subsequently been removed.

Have no idea where to look or what to do. Any (sensible) suggestions welcome. Please note, this is only happening since upgrading to RoR4.

```
rails (4.0.0)
  actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
  actionpack (= 4.0.0)
  activerecord (= 4.0.0)
  activesupport (= 4.0.0)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.0.0)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)

rspec (2.13.0)
  rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)

guard (1.8.2)
  formatador (>= 0.2.4)
  listen (>= 1.0.0)
  lumberjack (>= 1.0.2)
  pry (>= 0.9.10)
  thor (>= 0.14.6)

guard-rspec (3.0.2)
  guard (>= 1.8)
  rspec (~> 2.13)
```

Comment: Since you are using 'locations', are you geo-coding them, or otherwise connecting to an external service?

Comment: Yeah actually! Do you think there's a delay as such

Comment: Yes, for sure. It's likely that google geocoding service is failing due to the free-tier going over limits. Are you using "geocoder" ?

Comment: We do but we use bing for that very reason in testing :) I'm going to disable it and see

Comment: Same problem with it disabled... What doesn't make sense is that it's always the last test that fails and it's supposed to be random.

Comment: What do you mean "supposed to be random" ?

Comment: I have config.order = "random" in spec helper, that's all

Comment: OK, so you're saying that the order is random, but whatever spec is tested last always fails? Is this something you can put on github and/or reproduce in a new rails app?

Comment: It looks that way if those little dots are right.. It's a small spec in a big application that we can't publish sadly. Just lost with it now, it's only happening in one model too - my only thought would be to remove as many callbacks as possible from that and try again. However, I can't see why it fails 'most' times..

Comment: Yeah, without additional information I won't be able to help. Just reduce dependencies and reduce code until you have a minimal reproducible test case. and remember -- code doesn't just fail "sometimes" -- there's always a reason.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the time today. Much appreciated. Exactly, computers are logical, have not enjoyed this one.. S